# Denoising removes roughness details?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine, denoise

I am rendering a snow scene and for the roughness i have a voronoi texture to create a glittery look. However, when I render it, they disappear.. I think maybe the denoiser thinks they are fireflies? i tried using the intel denoiser but it did the same thing. I heard on another blender stack thread that its due to low samples, so i bumped it up to 200 and it still removed it.. How can I fix this? Currently, only idea I have is to just render it with no denoising and a high ammount of samples, but my pc isn't very fast.

In eevee:

[image]

With denoiser in cycles (100 samples):

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'd say Denoising works *much* better with 1000+ samples. Under 500 samples it's basically unusable.

Comment: I don't have a powerful PC, and i have never seen someone go above 500 samples with a denoiser. most of the time i can do 200 samples and get a good result@JachymMichal

Comment: 200 samples is still a very low number... Use more samples. It will take longer to render, that is how blender works.... and Yes, denoising removes detail, the issue is that, what is considered "noise" are big variations in terms of the values of surrounding pixels, which is exactly what you are trying to showcase, the texture you are dealing with is noisy by definition, so denoising is not going to help you, it actually works against you.